# MathJax 3: Inline Math and overflow-x

Tags: responsive, mathjax

It is very easy to handle overlapping display math.

We can add a class named `has-jax` to all display math elements...

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  document.querySelectorAll('mjx-container[jax="CHTML"][display="true"]').forEach(function(x){
      x.parentElement.classList.add('has-jax');
  });
});
```

and then define in our css file

```
.has-jax {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

But is there a way to add `overflow-x: auto` to inline math?

The problem is that `overflow-x` can only happen on `block` or `inline-block` level elements, because the element needs to have a width in order to be overflowed.

**Edit**

The solution below results in wrong aligned inline-math in Firefox browser on Linux Mint:

[image]

If I delete `display:inline-block` from the solution below the x+x+y is well aligned but the inline-math overflows the box.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `.has-jax`, but can style `mix-container` itself as follows:

```css
mjx-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>

<div style="width:15em; border: 1px solid; padding: 3px 5px">
This is some text with a long in-line math expression
\(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p+q+r+s+t+u+v+w+x+y+z\)
that we hope will have a scroll bar!  This math \(x+y+z\) should not.
Long display math also gets a scroll bar:
\[a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p+q+r+s+t+u+v+w+x+y+z\]
</div>
```

This will also provide display-mode math with scroll bars if they are too long.  If you want to do this *only* for inline math, then use `mjx-container:not([display])` instead.

Here is a screen snapshot of the result:

[image]

Comment: There is a bug in your solution: Where it says `This math \(x+y+z\)` the x+y+z is not well aligned in the line.

Comment: @Sr.Schneider.  It looks good to me.  What browser are you using, and what OS?  I added screen snapshot to show how it looks.

Comment: I use Firefox on Linux Mint. I added a screenshot to my question so you can see the issue.

Comment: @Sr.Schneider, if you edit my answer and remove the `display: inline-block`, is the inline math properly aligned?

Comment: Yes, but then the inline-math overflows the box. I added another screenshot.

Comment: @Sr.Schneider, Yes, I knew that would happen, I just wanted to determine if it was the `display` setting that was causing the issue.  I'll look into it further.

Comment: @Sr.Schneider, sorry not to get back to you sooner.  I was sick in bed all day yesterday, but am doing better today.  It turns out that the combination of `display:inline-block` with `overflow` other than `visible` causes the result to have its bottom sit on the baseline (like an image) rather than to match the baselines.  At least that is the case of Firefox and Chrome (but no Safari).  So it will take something more sophisticated.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: Take your time, Davide. I think this is not easy to solve.

Comment: @Sr.Schneider, it looks like `inline-grid` or `inline-flex` works in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome.  I've updated the code above, so give it a try.

Comment: It looks good now. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

For display mode, use:

```css
mjx-container {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

For inline mode, use the answer from [Davide Cervone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65381823/7341454)

```css
mjx-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Tested and works well on MathJax V2, MathJax V3, KaTeX.